# Installation of Expression Studio 3 fails

Tags: installation, expression-blend

Trying to install Expression Studio 3 on an XP box with 3GB of RAM and amazingly the install fails with Out Of Memory error.

And the install truly does take up a huge amount of RAM.
[alt text http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/gpf.png](http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/gpf.png)
[alt text http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/taskman.png](http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/taskman.png)

Am I missing something?  Or does it require more that 3GB (never seen that before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.  You won't believe the solution.  Minimize the installer window while the installation is running and it should finish okay.  For some reason having the installer window visible leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

Along with DMKing's solution you can always run from the command line in silent mode:

[Location]\setup.exe" -q -params:ProductTag:param=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

where location is the setup file location. Also if your copy is from the MSDN you wont need the -params:ProductTag:param=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX as the key is pre pitted.